# javascript $ sign is not working as dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
<Link onClick={(event) => (!name || !room) ? event.preventDefault() : null} to={"/chat?name=${name}&room=${room}"} >
            <button className="button mt-20" type="submit">Sgn In</button>
        </Link>
```

value should be passed through this dynamicaly typed ${name} and ${room} but they are not working as they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use backticks for Template Strings ([String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Your Link should look like this:

```
<Link onClick={(event) => (!name || !room) ? event.preventDefault() : null} to={`/chat?name=${name}&room=${room}`} >
            <button className="button mt-20" type="submit">Sgn In</button>
 </Link>
```